# Why is typescript compiler omitting 'should.js' import in generated javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js, should.js

I am facing a weird issue. In my (lets say) `a.ts` I have -

```
/// <reference path="../typings/mocha/mocha.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/should/should.d.ts" />

import should = require('should');

import something_else = require('../something-else');
```

Now when I compile using command -

```
tsc -m commonjs --outDir "./build" "src/test/a.ts"
```

My generated javascript is not having `require` for `should` -

```
/// <reference path="../typings/mocha/mocha.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/should/should.d.ts" />
var service_manager = require('../routes/service-manager');
```

This seems like a bug in typescript compiler, but I may be doing it incorrectly. Or if there is some workaround, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does that because you are not using it. It will stick as soon as you you actually use the `should` variable. e.g.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/mocha/mocha.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/should/should.d.ts" />

import should = require('should');
var persist = should;
```

Reason: It allows you to use type information on its own without taking a runtime dependency on `require('should')`. It also allows you to do lazy loading in AMD scenarios.

Comment: But I am using it in mocha test. Like - `res.body.should.equal('');`

Comment: You need to use the variable that require returns

Comment: Just use the `var persist` trick i've updated the answer with

Comment: Its a hack, but it works! More importantly thanks for the reason.

Comment: This would also work if you omitted "import should =" and just had "require('should');"

Comment: When I omit ```import should =``` I get tsc compile error: TS2304: cannot find name "require".

Comment: @John if you are not using `import` and raw require you need raw require lib e.g `node.d.ts`

Answer (score 1):

As the comment by [Eric Nicholson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45802/eric-nicholson), just `require` without `import`.

```
require('should');
// use should
```

Besides, those `reference path` would be bundled at `typings/tsd.d.ts` by default and no need to write in individual file.