# TypeError: should is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, should.js

I have recently upgraded to Angular 6 and all the tests that ran fine fail with the following error

> TypeError: should is not a function

I am using Angular-Cli 6 and my best guess is this is because appropriate typings aren't available for 'should' (npm-package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/should )

I have the following two lines added to every file that uses the should function.

```
import should = require('should');
const persist = should; // need to use should library for tests to run https://stackoverflow.com/a/25563303/1373856
```

Also, I am using  "typings": "2.1.1"
Anyone faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you include a dependency into your tests (at least, that's not how I learnt it).

Open `karma.conf.js`. Under the `plugins` export, add your dependency :

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('should'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      ...
```

Now, in your test files, you just have to declare a variable as a reference to your global function :

```
declare var should: any;
```

If you have typings, you can also type it to have intellisense in your IDE.